# HTML annotation with JSOUP

Tags: javascript, html, css, annotations, jsoup

I would need to automatically annotate web pages based on the textual content of the web pages. For instance I want to annotate html content where there are city and add a span like:

`barcelona --> <span class="city">barcelona</span>`

The problem is that I know the position of the cities based on textual content and not on html. Previously I have worked with JSoup, but I could not find how can  found the position to insert tags based on textual positions.

Comment: Hi, it would be nice if you can also add the whole HTML content with what your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to acheive your goal:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<p>Barcelona is a nice place to live !<br/>Other cities <b>too</b>!</p>");
    dumpDocument("** BEFORE **", doc);

    Matcher replacer = Pattern.compile("(?i)(barcelona)").matcher("");
    for (Element elt : doc.body().select("*")) {
        for (TextNode textNode : elt.textNodes()) {
            String originalText = textNode.text();

            if (replacer.reset(originalText).find()) {
                String annotatedHtml = replacer.replaceAll("<span class=\"city\">$1</span>");
                textNode.before(annotatedHtml);
                textNode.remove();
            }
        }
    }
    dumpDocument("** AFTER **", doc);
}

private static void dumpDocument(String title, Document doc) {
    System.out.println(title);
    System.out.println(doc.html());
    System.out.println();
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
** BEFORE **
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <p>Barcelona is a nice place to live !<br>Other cities <b>too</b>!</p>
 </body>
</html>

** AFTER **
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <p><span class="city">Barcelona</span> is a nice place to live !<br>Other cities <b>too</b>!</p>
 </body>
</html>
```